# Change pages with Spinner

Tags: android

I created a spinner populated with values from a string array in my "strings.xml. When a user selects an item in the spinner I would like it to redirect them to that page, and then be able to return to the main page via a back button.

How do you send them to another page via a spinner selection?

Comment: What do ou mean by page? Maybe you want to start a subactivity?

Comment: If you wanna start a new activity, you choosed the wrong way.
It is not recommanded to use spinner to launch activities. Spinner is used to change parameters, data, variable on a current activities but certainly not to do this.
You can used it like that but it's so bad for GUI.
The best way to start new activity in running, it's the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [on tem selection listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getOnItemSelectedListener%28%29). In the listener's onItemSelected method, you'd use position to determine the selected position in the array. Based on the position, you know which string was clicked. Then you'd create an Activity for each "page" and start the appropriate activity.

Comment: Thanks, I am still pretty new to android, and I am not completely sure what tools I have available.

Comment: At 10,000 feet, page == activity. You switch between pages using Intents. Won't take long to get the hang of.